# Add Strings to Map

Tags: java

I have two `String` arrays of the same size.

I need to make a `Map` with name and value. How do I add them to the `Map`?

```
String[] labelNames = request.getParameterValues("labelName");
String[] labelValues = request.getParameterValues("labelValues");
Map<String,String> labels = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the `labelName` and `labelValues` arrays are not the same length?

Comment: Why not just call request.getParameterMap()?

Answer (score 2):

You have `arrays` of same size, so you can iterate over them with the same `for-loop`, you'll access same `index` on both and `put` them into the `map` :

```
for(int i=0; i<labelNames.length; i++){
    labels.put(labelNames[i], labelValues [i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you got 2 arrays where the size is the same just make a for-loop which uses the `labelName` and the `labelValue`

```
for(int i = 0; i < labelNames.length; i++) {
    labels.put(labelNames[i], labelValues[i]);
}
```

if you're not sure if the size of the two arrays is the same add this check before the loop:

```
if(labelNames.length == labelValues.length) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for Java 7 - you can use the `for` loop structure with a single index to advance into the 2 arrays at the same time.

As for the assumption `labelNames.length == labelValues.length` it is usually better to always check it to make sure you didn't introduce a bug and get unexpected results:

```
if(labelNames.length == labelValues.length) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < labelNames.length; i++) {
        labels.put(labelNames[i], labelValues[i]);
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you could use `Streams` as an alternative:

```
Map<String, String> map =
        IntStream.range(0, names.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> labelNames[i], i -> labelValues[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
Map<String,String> labels = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<labelNames.length;i++)
    labels.put(labelNames[i] , labelValues[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
 Map<String,String> labels = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and then:

```
for (int i=0; i < labelNames.length; i++) 
{
  labels.put(labelNames[i], labelValues[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is already 5 times this answer, no need to spam

Comment: It takes a minute or two to write an answer. In the meantime other users may publish solutions.